# Approximation formula for the Kummer function ${}_1F_1(a, b, x)$ for large $x$?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

The question here: [Asymptotics of Kummer Hypergeometric Function in first argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523892/asymptotics-of-kummer-hypergeometric-function-in-first-argument?rq=1)
addresses asymptotics for the first argument of a Kummer function. However, it is a very special case, and does not address the question of asymptotics in the last argument. So, I have been trying to get an answer to how the approximation formula for ${}_1F_1(a, b, x)$  is derived for the case of large $x$. (The suggested approach in the comment does not apply for $a>b$.)

According to 13.1.4 of Abramowitz and Stegun, as $x \rightarrow\infty$,we get
$${}_1F_1(a, b, x) = \frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)}\exp{(x)}x^{a-b}\{1 + {\mathcal O}(1/x)\},$$
but I am trying to figure out how this result arises, and in particular what would be a good approximation for ${}_1F_1(a, b, x)$ for large $x$.

A similar approximation is stated in  13.2.(iv) in https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2#iv where the result is in the form of $\mathbf  M(a,b,x) = \frac{{}_1F_1(a,b,x)}{\Gamma(b)}$.

For numerical approximations to the ${}_1F_1(a, b, x) $, I need to know how to derive this relation for large $x$. I am looking for a general $a$, $b$ and $x>0$.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the integral representation 13.2.1.

Comment: Thanks, @Gonçalo. That formula is for $b > a > 0$. What if $a > b > 0$?

Comment: I don't know. ${}$

Comment: [13.2.(iv)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2#iv) in DLMF refers to $\mathbf{M}(a,b,z)$, defined in [13.2.4](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2#E4) as $M(a,b,z)=\Gamma(b)\mathbf{M}(a,b,z)$. Therefore, both approximations are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks very much @Gonçalo , edited!